# Excluding specific words prior to a searched word in perl

Tags: regex, sas

In my text string: `STAPH AUREAS ISOLATED.  NO STAPH AUREAS RESISTANCE DONE`, I want to extract all occurances of `STAPH AUREAS` *only* if it is NOT preceded by `NO`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Consider the `index` function for such a specific search...

Comment: What do you mean by *"extract"*?

Comment: I should have added a SAS tag to my question.  I'm actually using a function called prxparse to identify specific text and only if the text is not preceded by "NO".

Comment: @user3919989: That doesn't matter a great deal, but please answer: *"What have you tried so far?"* and *"What do you mean by "extract"?"*

Comment: You mean [tag:regex], not [tag:perl].  Perl is just the flavor of regex that you're using in SAS.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`perlretut` - Looking ahead and looking behind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind).

In this instance, I'd recommend using a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<!NO )your_pattern
```